# Input[type=range]. Как добавить transition к ползунку и сделать проверку на value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, css-animation

Привет!
Как добавить transition к ползунку в input range, и реально сделать это вообще?
Меня интересует такое движение ползунка
[image]
Обратите внимание на окончание гифки, здесь видно, что ползунок в конце отпускают и тот возвращается на свое место (в соответствии с условием js).
Мой код [codepan](https://codepen.io/Richswitch/pen/RLWXyV)

```js
var sliderChange = document.querySelector('input[type=range');

sliderChange.onchange = function() {
  sliderChangeStyle();
  sliderChangeFunc();
};

// trigger input start
var event = new CustomEvent('input'); // create event
sliderChange.dispatchEvent(event); // trigger event

sliderChange.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  sliderChangeStyle();
  sliderChangeFunc();
}, false);

// trigger input end

// styles func
function sliderChangeStyle() {
  var value = sliderChange.value,
    min = sliderChange.getAttribute('min'),
    max = sliderChange.getAttribute('max');
  sliderChange.style.backgroundSize = (value - min) * 100 / (max - min) + '%' + ' 100%';
};
// styles 


//motion slide start
var slideFirst = document.getElementById('slideItemFirst'),
  slideSecond = document.getElementById('slideItemSecond'),
  slideThird = document.getElementById('slideItemThird');

function sliderChangeFunc() {
  var value = sliderChange.value;
  var defaultVal = 0,
    shift = 1024;

  if (value < 25) {
    console.log('value < 25');
  } else if (value > 25 && value < 50) {
    console.log('value > 25 && value < 50');
  } else if (value >= 50 && value < 100) {
    console.log('value >= 50 && value < 100');
  } else {
    console.log('else');
  }

};
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 15px;
  width: 690px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, green);
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-image: url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/9/449/w256h2561380452221DriveNetwork.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin-right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="sliderInput" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил сделать так: сначала находим нормализованое значение слайдера (0,...0.5...,1) для плавности я решил использовать `cos` нормализованого значения, затем используется простая линейная интерполяция для того что-бы понять положение на экране по `x`.

```js
let slider = $('#slider');
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block').each(function(){
    $(this).css("top", $(window).height()*Math.random());
    $(this).attr("data-start", Math.random()*($(window).width()+400));
    $(this).attr("data-end", Math.random()*$(window).width());
    $(this).css("left", $(this).attr('data-start')+"px");
  });
});
slider.on('input', function(){
  let max = slider.prop('max');
  let value = slider.prop('value');
  let normalized = value/max;
  normalized = (Math.cos(normalized*3.14+3.14)+1)/2; //Для плавности
  $('.block').each(function(){
    $(this).css("left", $(this).attr('data-start')-normalized*$(this).attr('data-end')+"px");
  });
});
```

```css
body
{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.block
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: teal;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="slider">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй событие `input` вместо `change`:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector("input");


inp.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.getElementById("input").textContent = e.target.value;
});

inp.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  document.getElementById("change").textContent = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
output { display: block; }
output:before { content: attr(id) ": "; }
```

```html
<input type=range min=0 max=100>
<output id="input"></output>
<output id="change"></output>
```